# How do I Authenticate my FTX_Client in Python

Tags: python, api, rest, authentication

I have looked through the FTX api documentation found here: https://docs.ftx.us/#overview

And I've looked at example code found in this repo: https://github.com/ftexchange/ftx/tree/master/rest

I can't 'get' or 'post' anything that requires the Authentication. I am using the api key on my account that has 'full trade permissions', and when I look at: print(request.headers) the headers look like they are in the right format.

I've tried: using google colab instead of vs code, updating all my libraries, generating a new api key, restarting kernel and computer. I can pull something like 'markets' because it doesn't need the Authentication.

Let me know if you need any more information, below is a portion of the code I have that isolates the problem and returns `{'success': False, 'error': 'Not logged in'}`

```
import time
import urllib.parse
from typing import Optional, Dict, Any, List

from requests import Request, Session, Response
import hmac

ep = 'https://ftx.us/api/wallet/balances'
ts = int(time.time() * 1000)
s = Session()
request = Request('GET', ep)
prepared = request.prepare()

signature_payload = f'{ts}{prepared.method}{prepared.path_url}'.encode()
if prepared.body:
    signature_payload += prepared.body
signature = hmac.new(secret.encode(), signature_payload, 'sha256').hexdigest()

request.headers['FTX-KEY'] = key
request.headers['FTX-SIGN'] = signature
request.headers['FTX-TS'] = str(ts)

response = s.send(prepared)
data = response.json()
print(data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've faced with the same problem.

You need to change this part:

```
prepared.headers['FTX-KEY'] = key
prepared.headers['FTX-SIGN'] = signature
prepared.headers['FTX-TS'] = str(ts)
```

PS. I believe that the FTX needs to fix their API documentation

PSS. I've checked the a part of https://github.com/ftexchange/ftx/tree/master/rest code. I beleave FTX guys just do a copy-paste into docs this code but originally it belongs to more a sophisticated object oriented solution that will work correctly because they pass into method an already created `request` and use a `prepared` variable just to calculate `path_url` and `method`

Comment: Thanks! I will try this when I get home and let you know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

For ftx.us, you need to use different headers:

```
        prepared.headers['FTXUS-KEY'] = key
        prepared.headers['FTXUS-TS'] = str(ts)
        prepared.headers['FTXUS-SIGN'] = signature
```

Comment: I will try this thank you!